# React MUI Autocomplete - Customizing renderInput content

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the React MUI Autocomplete component like in the [countries example](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#country-select) from the official doc.

My goal is **to display in bold the country code**, as I already did in the renderOption by simply enclosing the option.code value with HTML tags.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';

export default function CountrySelect() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="country-select-demo"
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      options={countries}
      autoHighlight
      getOptionLabel={(option) => `${option.code} ${option.label}`} // DISPLAY THE CODE
      renderOption={(props, option) => (
        <Box component="li" sx={{ '& > img': { mr: 2, flexShrink: 0 } }} {...props}>
          <img
            loading="lazy"
            width="20"
            src={`https://flagcdn.com/w20/${option.code.toLowerCase()}.png`}
            srcSet={`https://flagcdn.com/w40/${option.code.toLowerCase()}.png 2x`}
            alt=""
          />
          {option.label} (<b>{option.code}</b>) +{option.phone}
        </Box>
      )}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Choose a country"
          inputProps={{
            ...params.inputProps,
            autoComplete: 'new-password', // disable autocomplete and autofill
          }}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit CountrySelect Material Demo (forked)]

I cannot find a way to reference the option.code inside the renderInput property, so I cannot figure out how to display the country code in bold *also* in the renderInput, since the bold is only visible when choosing an option, but not when that option is selected.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with this is that MUI Textfields consist of HTML `<input/>` tags.

Its value can only be of type string which prohibits any direct value styling but you can make use of an `startAdornment` like so:

```
...
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Choose a country"
          inputProps={{
            ...params.inputProps,
            autoComplete: "new-password" // disable autocomplete and autofill
          }}
          InputProps={{
            ...params.InputProps,
            startAdornment: <strong>{params.inputProps.value.split(" ")[0]}</strong>
          }}
        />
      )}
...
```

Your next challenge would be to remove the additional country code from the input-value or even better, move to a controlled value approach.